# Describe an "atom" of conversation

Tags: single-word-requests

Loosely speaking, a conversation involves two parties variously exchanging statements/sentences/remarks. I'm looking for a word that describes a single statement-response exchange. Of course, *exchange* comes to mind, but it doesn't exclude a longer/larger exchange involving multiple statement-response events. I hope there's something more specific.

Comment: A number of choices come to mind. One that stands out is the term 'converse' or 'conversing'.

Comment: Thanks, but similarly to "exchange" those don't exclude longer-form exchanges involving multiple statements and responses.

Comment: "Transaction" bears a close resemblance to your requirements, but I am not sure it is used to describe a conversational exchange.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful contribution. You're right, it's a little contextually unusual, but it's the best I have so far!

Comment: Is the idea 'question-response' or 'statement-response'? (not extending beyond a pair)

Comment: Yes, something like a single exchange in which each of two participants participates exactly once.

Comment: There may not be a word for this, since there may not be anything to discuss meaningfully about such "atoms". Individual sentences are statements are interesting, but alternating pairs not such much.

Comment: But maybe if you asked on a linguistics board, they might have some jargon they use for it.

Comment: Statement - response isn't really an atom because two statements may come in a row.

Comment: It's a bit simplistic to reduce "conversation" to a series of *statement-response* exchanges. In many if not most real-world interactions you could just as easily analyse the *statement* as a "response" to whatever came before, and the *response* as provoking whatever comes next. So it's somewhat artificial to pick out any given consecutive pair of contributions and call it one of the "atomic building blocks" of the complete conversation.

Comment: Two "statements" from one person is still one half of an exchange, one "atom" in the conversation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I do agree that my definition of a conversation is incomplete, and that my so-called "atom" can be interlaced with other atoms. However, arbitrariness of order is something I specifically didn't preclude in my question; I agree that statement-response is identical to statement-statement and to response-statement. (I hope this makes sense). Barmar, it's beginning to look like you're probably correct. Thanks everyone for your thoughts + help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: @mkingston: It's a bit like trying to analyse tennis rallies by always focusing on two consecutive hits (one from each player). The first and last hits in the whole rally have their own "special significance", but mostly you need to take account of what comes before *and* after each hit (and so it goes on recursively, since everything has both causes and effects).

Answer (score 2):

How about "volley", a metaphor from tennis or volleyball?

Comment: It's not bad. I'd probably still prefer "transaction", I think it's probably less contextually unusual. I think (rather subjectively) that volley would be brilliant in the context of an argument or debate. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **a single exchange** would work for you.

Comment: I was hoping for something more succinct, but thanks anyway.